# How to make microphone work on HP laptop?

Tags: hp, microphone

I'm using Ubuntu on a HP laptop, more specifically an EliteBook 830 G7. Everything seems to work well right now except for the microphone. When I have meetings on Microsoft Teams no one can hear what I'm saying. The microphone I can choose is named "Comet Lake PCH-LP cAVS Digital Microphone".

Any idea for how I can troubleshoot or fix this issue?

Edit: I'm using ubuntu 22.04.1.

Comment: First what version of Ubuntu are you using? Please read the information on this site https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @David: I added the version in the original post. Thanks for the link. I think I'm following the instructions.